# Antique X-Ray Tube Safety

Tags: x-rays, laboratory-safety

[image: Antique X-Ray tube]
I have this antique X-Ray tube in my lab.  As far as I can tell it's a “Kesselring” free anti-cathode tube from about the 1920s.  Is there a *safe* way to operate this tube and make some x-rays or is this one of those cases where if I have to ask I shouldn't try it.

Comment: Actually this is a demonstration model and we used to run it in class demonstration for undergraduate/graduate students. If you have black curtains on the window the details can be seen by students. this was run by an induction coil whose primary was given a 12 v d,c, supply from battery and  as the secondary had large number of turns it provided about 20 kv of a.c. which was fed to the tube. a glow of cathode rays could be seen and the x-ray produced was of such intensity that  a hand impression on ZnS plate could be shown to the students- those bone shadows...

Comment: @drvrm: I would not consider such an experiment "safe" by modern standards. I am not sure why anybody would want to "experiment" with ionizing radiation to begin with. Radiation physics doesn't turn interesting until one has expended a significant amount of effort and money on proper nuclear instrumentation and data analysis techniques, at which point it is rather tedious (I know, I have done it for a living for a while). In general: non-ionizing radiation is a lot more physically interesting and enjoyable than ionizing radiation. Unless you are a professional, stick to visible light!

Comment: We found something similar here, while cleaning out the prep room for a move to temporary quarters. It is destined for the display case when the re-model of our space done. You could operate it behind a bunch of shielding, but what would you gain by doing so?

Comment: @CuriousOne  As regards safety is concerned -its not a problem as the intensity is not large(thetube current is small) and we do cathode rays demonstration /like showing crooks dark spaces - as nobody has seen electrons even -so for young minds its exciting and historical as Sir Roentzen's X-rays coming out! my personal experience is that until i did work with reactor beam the nuclear thing seemed hazy-safety measures can be managed- boys were not close to the apparatus.

Comment: @drvrm: 1) Who is going to do reliable dosimetry here? 2) There are no electrons to be seen here. All you are seeing is light that comes from some strange tube while a teacher you usually don't like talks about stuff you don't care about (that's the reality of high school physics). Once you can see the electrons themselves (lighting up your eyeballs), it's really to late to worry, anyway. 3) ERGO: It's not worth it. Leave ionizing radiation to the pros. If you want to become a pro: nothing stops you.

Comment: The dosimetry is the really stinker and the reason a E&HS rep would look askance at using this thing for a classroom demo. If you *really* want to run it for the cool factor, take video of yourself demonstrating it, then show the video. Our new display case is going to have a video-display on the opposite wall, so if we run ours we'll put the video in the loop the screen shows. The place these things hold in the history of physics is important and worth explaining, but is it worth a unmetered (if probably small) dose delivered to a lot of students?

Answer (score 3):

X-ray tech here. Only use this if everyone is behind 2.5mm lead or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Given the cones are eroded, its likely the ionized particles surrounding them can cause cancer.